# Is LaTeX a viable choice for programmatically designing "Desktop Publishing" documents?

Tags: database, layout

I am currently working on a project where one of the end products is a PDF datasheet. That datasheet consists of text, images, tables, and lists. We would be generating the .tex file programmatically.

We have generally rendered datasheets as HTML and used a third-party application to convert that HTML to PDF. HTML to PDF is a very unwieldy and uncontrollable solution.

I have used LaTeX here and there in the past to create PDFs. In all cases, I  have never had issues dialing in the design of the documents. These documents have all been straightforward.

I am considering using LaTeX to set up these documents, but I want to make sure that I will be able to control the following:

- Fonts: I am guessing that the client will want to tweak the fonts here and there. Not specifying a font, but maybe defining a font family.
- Tables: the tables will need to have some background coloring, and maybe different outline widths and styles. We will need to adjust where the pages break when rendering a table.
- Lists: We will probably need to adjust line-height in the lists
- Images: We will need to scale and place the image within a few mm.
  Does this sound like it might be a good fit?

Is there somewhere I can find a gallery of "Desktop Publishing" type documents generated with LaTex?

Comment: You could also consider using ConTeXt which has XML processing capabilities and the typesetting capabilities of TeX including everything you asked for. In my experience, it's better for automation. Alternatively, there's speddata publisher (also TeX).

Answer (score 2):

This is a commercial site but has some good examples:

https://www.latextypesetting.com/showcase#creation-modification

In particular, *Financial ETF Report*

> The goal of this project was to produce a financial ETF report template that matched a designer mock-up in appearance, but **could be populated entirely programatically** to automatically produce such reports for different ETF symbols. This meant that all elements on the page must be added using custom commands with expected arguments to create each box and populate the company information. As the boxes of information could contain varying numbers of lines, a key requirement was for the box heights to adjust per row so a shorter box would be forced to be the same height as a taller box next to it to maintain consistency across the page. The tcolorbox package was used to this end and customised extensively to allow creating the boxes, their headings and content using only custom commands. Another requirement was for a long table that could automatically span multiple pages using automatically populated content.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, LaTeX can be used for such documents. As you noted, some things are challenging:

- You can use OpenType and TrueType fonts --- see the `fontspec` documentation --- loading a family is the default
- There are various packages for tables, I'm partial to `booktabs`, but I'm a stuffy, old-fashioned kinda guy --- for fancy tables with colours and such, you'll want to find a suitable package
- yes, there are controls / options for typesetting of lists which allow one to adjust such things --- a cautionary note is that ConTeXt began as a package which afforded greater control over typesetting of lists --- you may want to consider jumping straight to it
- image scaling / handling is good / easy --- use the package `grffile` for filenames, and `graphicx` for the niceties it affords --- you can scale based on document dimensions such as page, column, or text block width or height, and it's pretty straight-forward to programmatically adjust based on the proportions of a document (landscape format graphics go to two-column while portrait are left at one is a typical adjustment)

There's the TeX Showcase: http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/